# StackPanel in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee

Is there any way I can display the stack panel in using swing. I have tried and googled various option but could not find anything relevant. Please give me an idea.

Comment: are you meaning StackPanel from GWT ???

Comment: No I did not mean StackPanel from GWT. I was asking idea how can we write STACKPANEL in Swing which would be the best approach I don't know why my question got -1. and I know there is no such thing in Swing API

Comment: I don't know too, not your donw-voter, but be sure that down-voting is about too lokalized something about STACKPANEL, I'm out off context to because for me Stack == Securities, if yes then there are lots of examples around

Comment: I am just scared because my last account get locked due to downvoting and I don't want this with this account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errr... A lot of confusion here.  Let me see if I can add to it.
Swing has a CardLayout, into which you can put plain JPanels.
So, make a JPanel, give a Cardlayout as the manager.
Cardlayout handles displaying JPanels (or other controls) on top of others.
I hope I understood, and that my answer helps.

Comment: thanks fred ... even I don't know why my question is downvoted as I made it clear that there is no stackpanel in swing and I was just checking the logic

Comment: Maybe you could point out, that you mean the StackPanel from WPF. I made +1 I just need it :)

Comment: Sorry guys but I really do not see how a CardLayout can be used to create a component behaving like a GWT StackPanel

Answer (score 4):

There's a StackPanel component in .NET and GWT, and each does different things.

The Swing component closest to the .NET StackPanel is a JPanel with a BoxLayout, with either horizontal or vertical orientation for the components.

If you meant GWT, use a JPanel with a CardLayout, which lays the contained UI components out so that only one is visible at a time.

The Oracle docs are pretty useful, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html for BoxLayout, and FlowLayout is next in the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such `StackPanel` in Java swing API.

Comment: Thanks AVD and I knew that ... I was taking your opinion that which panel would be best if we write Stackpanel in swing

Answer (score 2):

If you mean [`com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.StackPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/StackPanel.html), there is no corresponding standard Swing component. As an alternative, consider `org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline`, shown [here](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/StackPanel.html). Limit the model to two levels, and limit the number of open nodes in the `OutlineModel`'s [`TreePathSupport`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/TreePathSupport.html).